# How do I change my username?

Tags: support, android-app

I have been actively using Stack Exchange app for some days now.

In my account page, in the place of userID, it says user470992. How can I change it to something of my choice. I am using the app in Android platform.

Please provide step by step solution.

Also, how do I log into Stack Exchange in my other devices with this account?

Comment: That can't be done from the app I think. Login on the website and change it there

Comment: @rene login? How?

Comment: You're logged in here, right? See https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/172413/how-can-i-change-my-username you can visit https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/373856/user470992 and then click Edit profile